# how can i get all row key from column family in cassandra cli?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, cassandra, cassandra-cli

fetch all rowkey from column family in cassandra cli using hector

```
val query=HFactory.createRangesliceQuery(keyspace,le,se,se)
query.setColumnFamily("myInfo").setKeys(Integer.MIN_VALUE,Integer.MAX_Value).execute()
```

OR

```
val query=HFactory.createRangesliceQuery(keyspace,le,se,se)
query.setColumnFamily("myInfo").setKeys(Integer.MIN_VALUE,Integer.MAX_Value).setRange("","",true,10).execute()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this will helps you

```
val rangeSlice = HFactory.createRangeSlicesQuery(keyspace, se, se, se)
rangeSlice.setColumnFamily("myInfo")
rangeSlice.setKeys(null, null)
rangeSlice.setRange(null, null, true, Int.MaxValue)
val bIterator = rangeSlice.execute().get.iterator()
while (bIterator.hasNext()) {
  val myRow = bIterator.next()
  val myKey = myRow.getKey()
  println(myKey+"<<<this is key")
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    val rangeSlice = HFactory.createRangeSlicesQuery(keyspace, se, se, se)
rangeSlice.setColumnFamily("myTable")
rangeSlice.setReturnKeysOnly();
val bIterator = rangeSlice.execute().get.iterator()
while (bIterator.hasNext()) {
val myKey =bIterator.next().getKey()
 println(myKey+"<<<this is key")
}
```

it will also work